# jsDoc : How do I make the @return type of my method the type of a local variable from it?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm making a javascript project and I want to make it as clean as possible, and for that I'm using jsDoc at the top of my methods.
For one of them, I would like to know if it's possible to specify as a return type the type of a local variable ?

Like this :

```js
/**
* Add a component to the gameObject
* @param {Function} component to add
* @return {comp.constructor.name}
*/
addComponent(component){
    let comp = eval("new Tzu." + component.name + "({gameObject : this});");
    this.behaviors.push(comp);

    return comp;
}
```

I want the @return to be the type of ***comp***

Of course the line 4 is completely wrong

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like

```js
let test = 'test';

/**
 * @returns {typeof test}
 */
function doSomething(test) {
    return test;
}
```

As a side note, you really shouldn't use eval. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) for more information.

Comment: I tryed but "typeof comp" is "object". I think the problem is form eval() !
Do you know a better way to do what I was doing without eval ? 

(instantiate a class which is my arg)

Comment: Take a look at bracket notation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation

Comment: Oh wait ! it returns "object", that's what I wanted haha I'm a bit tired

Comment: Brackets work, you're a genius, that's way better !